# I'm using WinSCP, and language characters are being displayed as �

Tags: html, winscp

I've tried many things, and used many html templates. Still have the same problem. I'm a bit certain that there isn't anything wrong with my code but with WinSCP itself. The website is infomatikk.no

Characters æøå are being displayed as �.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Options > Preferences > Internal editor > Default encoding and set to UTF-8

Comment: But please try to avoid asking a question before searching for a solution properly. There are surely tons of sources about encoding in Winscp.

Comment: Hi! There was a pop up that said there is something wrong with the file that contains the UTF-8. Will redownload and give update. Thanks

Comment: I redownloaded WinSCP, but the problem remained. So i set notepad as the default editor. Saved it to my computer as UTF-8, took that file, swapped it out in the server. It worked!